# Hyphen vs. hyphenation

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[hyphen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) and [hyphenation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) are both tags on ELU. What's the purpose of the summary-less [hyphenation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) tag?

Comment: I’m marking this completed because these were made synonyms quite some time ago now.

Answer (score 4):

Questions when to use hyphens are still questions about hyphens, and I don't see any need to distinguish between questions about hyphens, and questions about using them.

I expect that most of the questions about hyphens (if not all the questions) are about its usage; I find difficult somebody asks "Is this an hyphen?" or "When was an hyphen first used?"

Answer (score -2):

Here’s how I see it:

- The [hyphen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) tag should be used for questions regarding the punctuation mark.
- The [hyphenation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) tag should be used for questions regarding where and whether something should be hyphenated.

These are actually different, different just as:

- [question-mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/question-mark) is different from [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions).
- [period](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/period) is different from  [sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentences).
- [exclamation-point](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exclamation-point) is different from [exclamations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exclamations).
- [quotation-marks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation-marks) is different from [quotations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotations).
- [apostrophe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostrophe) is different from [possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessive), and from [contractions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contractions).

Well, it could be worse: people could have asked to merge [hyphen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) with [dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dash).

Comment: They may be quite different to you, but I don't see much evidence that the questions are being tagged according to these distinctions. Nor do I see the point of going to that level, frankly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [tag:apostrophe] is different from [tag:possessive], just as [tag:question-mark] is different from [tag:questions], [tag:period] from  [tag:sentences], and [tag:exclamation-point] from [tag:exclamations].  See how different the punctuation is from the things where you use it?

Comment: I see they *are* different - but as I said, I don't see that difference as being something worth tracking with tags. In short, I see **how** different they are as "not enough". More to the point, the people actually using the tags aren't taking much notice of the distinction, so unless that changes it won't make much difference.

Comment: Presumably the difference should be made clear in the tags' wiki summaries. For *hyphenation* at least, that's not the case.

Comment: Are all _hyphen_ and _dash_ questions to be tagged under _hyphenation_? Do we have a dash tag, an en-dash tag, and an em-dash tag?

Comment: All those categories seem redundant to me.  If I was presented with a choice of tagging "hyphen" or "hyphenation" I would probably just randomly pick one, and what's the point of that.

Comment: "Question mark" is different from "questions" in that not all questions require a question mark (consider rhetorical questions and indirect questions) and not all question marks are attached to questions (e.g., sometimes you'll see `(?)` in the middle of a sentence). Similarly for most of your other examples. (Which isn't to say that they all *really* need separate tags, but at least it's conceivable that a question could merit one tag and not the other.) But hyphenation and hyphens are genuinely coextensive: you can't hyphenate without a hyphen, and you can't use a hyphen without hyphenating.